# How to remove notifications sent be oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an app that places triggers in oracle database table so that when there is a change like an insert or an update I get a notification in my program.
The app is suppose to remove those triggers after it closes but there is an error and sometimes they remain there in the database and I have no idea how to remove them since the can not remove triggers it does not know that exist.

In sqldeveloper it looks something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVl9k.jpg

How do I remove these ?
Thanks.

UPDATE:
in the morning the problem was solved by itself and the table was empty
but after running my app a few times it's again full with orphan change notifications and the program acts randomly. Sometimes I don't get any notification and sometimes I get multiple notifications for the same event in a row.

Does anyone actually know how to remove all change notifications from database using sqldeveloper or a simple program ?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. Also, please avoid [screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's hard to read the picture which's attached, and I wonder the reason to remove the related trigger.

But if you really need this, disabling the trigger maybe an alternative. Query *status* of the trigger from *user_triggers* data dictionary view :

```
SQL> SELECT 'Trigger Status is '||t.status||' now'  
       FROM user_triggers t 
      WHERE t.trigger_name='<your_trigger_name>';
```

where *t.status* returns *DISABLED* or *ENABLED*.

and if you want to disable, call the following from your application :

```
SQL> ALTER TRIGGER <your_trigger_name> DISABLE;
```

and anytime you can enable the trigger by calling :

```
SQL> ALTER TRIGGER <your_trigger_name> ENABLE;
```

Comment: Bizarrely after running the first command the change notifications dissapeared. I'm not sure if this caused it but thanks.

Comment: @RobertBanu excuse me, I forgot to remove INTO part. Perhaps it's caused by that. You're welcome.

Comment: It wasn't from that command. I encountered the error again. I think the database deletes the triggers itself if they aren't used for some time (that's what a colleague told me at least) and it just coincided with that moment

Comment: @RobertBanu there may be a scheduled job to perform such an operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your using change notifications not triggers. Read up more on change notifications: [26 Database Change Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer . I would like to be able to delete them from sqldeveloper and not java code if possible (I am using other person's library that does this changes so I don't have access to that particular code). Do you happen to know how can I do this ?